# My url is working on Postman but nerver in my website

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication

I have some problem with my authentification
This is created with axios and the frontend part is React

The backend running on port 3005 and front end working on port 3000.
In the postman, all API's works perfectly but when I try to integrate this in Front end he give me this error
`xhr.js:244     POST http://192.168.1.147/api/auth/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
This is my auth - controllers (login side)
`

```
exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  if(!email || !password){
    return next(new ErrorResponse("Introduceti email sau parola valida", 400))
  }

  try{
    const user = await User.findOne ({ email }).select("+password");

    if(!user){
      return next(new ErrorResponse("Credentiale nevalide", 401))
    }

    const isMatch = await user.matchPasswords(password);

    if(!isMatch){
      return next(new ErrorResponse("Credentiale nevalide", 401))
    }

    sendToken(user, 200, res);
     
  }catch(error) {
    res.status(500).json({ succes: false, error: error.message })
  }
};
```

`

This is my login page
`

```
import React from "react";
import { Navbar } from "../components/Navbar";
import { Footer } from './sections/Footer';
import RegisterIMG from '../assets/register.svg';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const Login = ({ history }) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        if(localStorage.getItem("authToken")){
            history.push("/");
        }
    }, [history]);

    const loginHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const config = {
            header: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }

        try {
            const {data} = await axios.post("http://192.168.1.147/api/auth/login" , { email, password }, config);

            localStorage.setItem("authToken", data.token);

            history.push("/");

        } catch (error) {
            setError(error.response.data.error);
            setTimeout(() => {
                setError("");
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
   

  return (
    <>
    <Navbar></Navbar>
    <div className="login-container">
        <div className="login-left">
            <div className="login-header">
                <h1>Conecteaza-te</h1>
                <p>Introduceti datele pentru logare</p>
                {error && <span className="error-message">{error}</span>}  
            </div>
            <form className="login-form" onSubmit={loginHandler}>
                <div className="login-form-content">
                    <div className="form-item">
                        <label /*for="emailForm"*/ htmlFor="email">Intruduceti email</label>
                        <input 
                        type="email" 
                        id="email" 
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        tabIndex={1}
                        required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-item">
                        <label /*for="passwordForm"*/ htmlFor="password">Introduceti parola</label>
                        <input 
                        type="password" 
                        id="password"
                        required
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        tabIndex={2}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="loginSubmit" tabIndex={3}>Conecteaza-te</button>
                </div>
                <div className="login-form-footer">
                <p>Nu ai cont?<a href="/register">Creeaza acum unul!</a></p>
                <p><a href="/forgotpassword">Ai uitat parola?</a></p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div className="login-right">
            <img src={ RegisterIMG } alt="image" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <Footer></Footer>
  </>


  );
};
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing the port while making the call to the back-end server.
Since your backend is deployed on PORT 3005 so the call should be as follows

```
const {data} = await axios.post("http://192.168.1.147:3005/api/auth/login", { email, password }, config);
```